# Laravel database connection to separate SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, laravel

I have a tricky one here that I'm looking for advice to see how much flexibility we have with a project.

We have a database that is hosted on a server locally that we can remote desktop into. I have the credentials and the domain example: SQL-CVW\BRADNAMS and I have the database name BRENT and the user and login that works for the program that the database feeds.

I can login to the remote desktop and open the database using SQL Server Management Studio but I need to be able to access it through Laravel.
I have tried using the sqlsrv setup in my .env file and I have the pdo_sqlsrv and sqlsrv php extensions installs.

I try to run php artisan migrate and I get the following error:

> SQLSTATE[08001]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: The wait operation timed out.
> (SQL: select * from sysobjects where type = 'U' and name = migrations)

Comment: So the server is another machine that is on our local network. I just was able to connect to it using Azure Data Studio on my local machine in office using SQL-CVIEW\BRADNAMS and my database name user and password. So connecting seems to work that way, I suppose the issue lies with how laravel is trying to do it?

Comment: How are you making Laravel connect using your own Windows account? Laravel is a PHP framework running in the context of a web server user. In the case of IIS (Internet Information Services) this means that, by default,  a Windows-authenticated SQL Server connection will be attempted using the `IIS_IUSR` account. Please edit the question to include your connection string settings and any related web.config changes.